# Sencha Touch - access 1 to 1 model relationship

Tags: json, extjs

I'm trying to access the following JSON from my model store.  I have no problem accessing the root (Name and Address) but i can't access anything in Financials (NetWorth or Income).  I've verified the JSON below is being returned from the server.

I know this has to be super easy but every example I've seen is showing how to access a 1 to many relationship.  My model is a 1 to 1.  Person->Financials.  Right now I don't have any associations setup as I don't know how to setup a 1 to 1 relationship.  I've tried associations, I've tried belongsTo, I've tried Financials.NetWorth from inside my itemTPL.  Nothing.

Can someone please show me the light?

**JSON returned from server**

```
[{
"PersonName": "John Smith", 
"Address": "123 main street",
"Financials": 
        [{
             "NetWorth": "$500,000", 
             "Income":"$67,000"
        }]
}]
```

**I registered my Models.**

```
Ext.regModel('Person', {
  fields: [
    {name: 'Name', type:'string'},
    {name: 'Address', type: 'string'},
  ],
});

Ext.regModel('Financials',{
  fields: [
    {name: 'NetWorth', type:'string'},
    {name: 'Income', type: 'string'},
  ],
});
```

**And registered the store**

```
var commStore = new Ext.data.Store({
            model: 'Person',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url : 'Business/GetData',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                }
            },
            autoLoad:false,
        });
```

**and displaying back in a list**

```
var commList = new Ext.List({
        fullscreen: false,
        itemTpl : '<div>{PersonName}</div><div>{Business.NetWorth}</div>',   
        store: commStore,
        height:500,
        width:"100%",
    });
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Beginner myself too, but it seems follwing could help (not tested with your code)

Have only on model:

```
Ext.regModel('Person', {
  fields: [
    {name: 'Name', type:'string'},
    {name: 'Address', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'NetWorth', type:'string', mapping 'Financials.NetWorth'},
    {name: 'Income', type: 'string', mapping 'Financials.Income'},
  ],
});
```

and in template code refer with the names

```
    itemTpl : '<div>{PersonName}</div><div>{Business.NetWorth}</div>',
```

becomes

```
    itemTpl : '<div>{PersonName}</div><div>{NetWorth}</div>',
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that your relationship is 1-to-1, but your JSON data returns an array(with 1 item, but nonetheless an array, because you use "[]" brackets) for Financials.
This means that Person should become something like this:

```
Ext.regModel('Person', {
  fields: [
    {name: 'Name', type:'string'},
    {name: 'Address', type: 'string'},
  ],
  hasMany: [
    {name: 'person', model: 'Person'}
  ]
});
```